# How to enable Reactive Repositories for Oracle database using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, reactive-programming

I have a requirement to work with Oracle database and Spring, I could easily choose Spring Data JPA, but all my programs should be [reactive](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/).

Like Spring supports Reactive Repositories for Couchbase and Mongo, as mentioned in [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data), **please help me enable Reactive Repositories for Oracle.**

I have already tried extending [ReactiveCrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html) from repository interface, but failed miserably as Spring Data JPA doesn't implement reactive API methods.

Comment: I don't think there is any relational databases which support reactive api

Comment: Please check this [comment](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data#comment-3727444532) ...

Comment: I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of the once cited.  This question is specifically asking about an Oracle database, which in this context may have an entirely different answer than MySql (depending on future vendor-specific driver implementations).